# How can I put an environment within a subsection?

Tags: environments, sections-paragraphs, code

I have this code, but the environment is put at the top of the page above the sections.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\lstnewenvironment{codice_c++}[1][]
{\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible,
keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries, commentstyle=\color{blue},
language=C++, basicstyle=\small,
numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,
stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, frame=shadowbox, float=*, #1}}{}
\begin{document} 

  \tableofcontents
        \newpage

  \section{s1}


\subsection{ss1}


\begin{codice_c++}[caption={c1}]
.....
 \end{codice_c++}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: check now....thx

Answer (score 2):

You have some options. Since you are using listings as floats, you may use `float=h` as the option

```
\begin{codice_c++}[float=h,,caption={c1}]
```

Also since you are using `placeins`, you can use `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` thereby restricting the placement of (all) floats within the section.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}     %% this will put all floats within their respective sections.
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\lstnewenvironment{codice_c++}[1][]
{\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible,
keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries, commentstyle=\color{blue},
language=C++, basicstyle=\small,
numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,
stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, frame=shadowbox, float=*, #1}}{}
\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents
        \newpage

  \section{s1}


\subsection{ss1}


\begin{codice_c++}[float=h,,caption={c1}]    %%% you may also use htbp
.....
 \end{codice_c++}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you decide not to float listings, you may use `caption` package and its `captionof` macro for inserting captions, but that is a different story.

Comment: ok it work, thx ;)

Comment: @Motosega Remember that the best way to say thanks over here is to accept answers that helped you. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)